# My KDE very slow in certain operations

Tags: linux, performance, kde, opensuse, kde-4

I have a problem with my Linux installation.

It seems that the KDE code that deals with directory windows is extremely slow (on both Dolphin and Konqueror). This happens both when I click on a directory icon and when I want to open/save a file from many KDE applications. The time the window takes to open can be one minute or more. The same happens when I right click on an icon.

Looking at the CPU usage, this is very low (less than 10%).

Am I the only one with this problem, or is it well known and maybe already fixed?

Consider that I cannot update to a more recent version of OpenSuse.

Thank you,
*Pietro*

**Configuration:**
Linux version: OpenSuse 11.4
KDE 4.6.0
System: DELL Precision T3500 - Intel Xeon
**Home directory mounted on a remote drive.** <-- *could this be the reason?*

Comment: Have you tried to turn off Nepomuk/Strigi?

Comment: @DragonJake: Nepomuk and Strigi seem to be core parts of KDE. Is it possible/worth turning them off? Is it possible to modify some settings to make them less resource-hungry? Even if resources are not a problem after all...

Comment: many users were/are complaining about uselessness and slowness of these KDE components. Appropriate settings could be found in _Personal Settings → Desktop Search_. Try to turn them off completely first to see if they were the problem.

Comment: I disabled both Nepomuk and Strigi. Nothing changed...

Comment: It was just a guess. Let's try something else, rename your `.kde`/`.kde4` directory and restart the X server. New KDE directory with default settings should be created. Does the problem still occur?

Comment: How _remote_ is `/home`? USB-drive, LAN, Internet (which speed)? Which tool are you using to determine CPU-usage? Probably it is disk-I/O anyway, a remote drive can be the issue here.

Comment: @WalterMaier-Murdnelch: /home is on a server on the same LAN. To determine CPU usage I use "top". Anyway I think it is neither a network nor a drive issue. The slow down happens even on local directories.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had this problem (though not with such extreme slowness) and it was related to graphics acceleration not working. Are desktop effects disabled in KDE settings? If not, disable them.

Comment: No, it does not depend on desktop effects. I disabled them with no improvement.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but intermittently.

Turns out the slow down only happens when there's a disc in my DVD drive.

For some reason, KDE re-reads the optical drive every time you switch to the file manager.

Comment: Not my case, unfortunately.